# Function that maps a rational number to its numerator and denominator

Tags: functions, fractions

**Question:** Is there a simple way to represent a  function $f:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Z^2$ that maps a rational number in lowest terms $r=\frac ab$ to the ordered pair of its numerator and denominator $(a,b)$?

By "simple", I mean anything necessary that involves just the value of $r$ itself and not actually $a$ and $b$.

This is just a question that interests me and that I'm curious about; it's not a homework problem or anything close to such. Obviously, a composition of elementary functions would be the most preferable for me, having learnt nothing past the rudiments of graduate-level algebra.

Feel free to re-tag if the tags aren't ideal.

Comment: Of course, you need to assume $a/b$ is a reduced fraction, i.e $(a,b)=1$, $b>0$. Your map will be from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Z^2$; in fact. Perhaps you can use Farey sequences, but I don't think it will be simple.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you, it's edited.

Comment: Is $r$ given as *some* fraction $c/d$?

Comment: @Travis It's given as simply $r$, and the image is its numerator and denominator.

Comment: @EdwardJiang Usually one constructs the rational numbers as equivalence classes of pairs $(c, d)$. So, we're handed a rational number but it's given as something like a real, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could define $f:\mathbb Q\rightarrow \mathbb Z^2$ to be the function such that, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $f(\frac{a}b)=(a,b)$. It's pretty clear that such a function exists. However, you're not going to be able to express it in terms of elementary functions because this $f$ would be everywhere discontinuous. This is problematic, because no composition of elementary functions is going to yield an everywhere discontinuous function.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I was clear in my question, otherwise it would be way to simple. The input is simply $r$, any rational number, not represented as a fraction.

Comment: @Edward My point is that the definition as a fraction is clearly well-defined, so we might as well use it; the main thing to note is that when we try to write it as $f(r)$ with elementary functions, we're doomed to try to appeal to continuity, since elementary functions are continuous (except at potentially countably many points). But $f$ is continuous nowhere, so this is impossible.